# Extracting sibling text nodes using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get certain text using beautiful soup, but I don't know how to get the text after a /strong tag. I found the content I am looking for but only want certain elements.

```
res = requests.get('http://www.fangraphs.com/statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
gamescore = soup.select('#content > table > tr > td > table > tr > td > div')
```

Output:
**Birthdate:** 8/7/1991 (25 y, 6 m, 12 d)     **Bats/Throws:** R/R

Is it possible to only get the birthdate and R/R out of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could select the `<strong>` elements based on their text and then select the adjacent sibling nodes using the [`next_sibling` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

```
birthday = soup.find('strong', text='Birthdate:').next_sibling.strip()
gamescore = soup.find('strong', text='Bats/Throws:').next_sibling.strip()
```

Output:

```
> print(birthday, gamescore)
> 8/7/1991 (25 y, 6 m, 12 d) R/R
```

---

If you want to select each of the `<strong>` elements and their next sibling nodes, then you could use the following:

```
elements = soup.select('#content > table table div > strong')

for element in elements:
    print(element.text, element.next_sibling)
```

Output:

```
> Birthdate:  8/7/1991 (25 y, 6 m, 12 d)     
> Bats/Throws:  R/R     
> Height/Weight:  6-1/235     
> Position:  OF
> Contract:
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks